# Import javascript file in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, import, svelte

So today I discovered [Svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte) and I absolutley love the concept. I only got one problem I wrote a small **helper.js** file and can't seem to import it. Every time I try to reference the class I get

> ReferenceError: Helper is not defined

*main.js file:*

```
import App from './App.svelte';
import './helper.js';

var app = new App({
    target: document.body
});
export default app;
```

*App.svelte file:*

```
<script>
    let helper = new Helper();
</script>

<h1>Hello</h1>
```

*helper.js file:*

```
class Helper {
  constructor() {
    console.log("working");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to import it into the file that uses it:

```html
<script>
  import Helper from './helper.js';
  let helper = new Helper();
</script>

<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but I also had to add 'export' in the Helper.js file. On that note: would there be another option to add the whole file without the 'import' statement. Like a <script src"Helper.js"><script> would do?

Comment: No, that would be a bad idea — you'll end up building much more maintainable software if your imports and exports are explicit

Comment: What about if you've got a legacy js file.  How do you include it?  It doesn't export anything.

Comment: Add it as a `<script>` tag

Comment: What to do when js module isn't exported with `default`?

Comment: @RichHarris In the above, will the application be reactive to any changes in the `helper` instance?