# Import stdlib.js in svelte

Tags: svelte

I am trying to develop a very simple browser app for some basic engineering calculations using [stdlib-js](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib) and [svelte](https://svelte.dev/) as a side learning project. Unfortunately, I am stuck at the very beginning because I have not been able to import stdlib-js into the svelte app.

First, to make things simple, I have downloaded a distributable bundle of stdlib-js ([stdlib-flat.min.js](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/blob/develop/dist/stdlib-flat.min.js)) locally to the same directory as App.svelte and main.js.

Then, I have made the simplest script possible to test that the library is correctly imported.

This is the *App.svelte* I have:

```html
<script>
    import * as stdlib from './stdlib-flat.min.js';
    var exp = stdlib.base.exp;
    var result = exp(.5);
</script>

<style>
    h1 {
        color: purple;
    }
</style>

<h1>The result is {result}!</h1>
```

And, inspired by the question [*Import javascript file in svelte*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839098/import-javascript-file-in-svelte/), I have modified the *main.js* to look like this:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';
import './stdlib-flat.min.js';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'world'
    }
});

export default app;
```

At this point, I get the following error:

```
(!) Missing exports
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
src/App.svelte
base is not exported by src/stdlib-flat.min.js
54: 
55: function instance($$self) {
56:   var exp = stdlib.base.exp;
                       ^
57:   var result = exp(.5);
```

And, as *exp* could not been defined, then the browser throws this error:

```
TypeError: exp is not a function App.svelte:4:18
    instance App.svelte:4
    init index.mjs:1259
    App bundle.js:317
    app main.js:4
    <anonymous> bundle.js:330
```

To check that [stdlib-js](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib) does work in the browser I loaded:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>stdlib-js test</title>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./stdlib-flat.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // `stdlib` is a global variable...
        var exp = stdlib.base.exp;
        console.log( exp( 0.5 ) );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it does.

Am I missing something? Does [stdlib-js](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib) need to be modified to export its functions?

Thanks in advance for your help and patience.

Comment: You probably need to do `import stdlib from '@stdlib/stdlib'` rather than `import * as stdlib ...`. Having said that, I'd strongly recommend *not* bundling this library — stdlib-flat.min.js is [2.59Mb in size](https://unpkg.com/browse/@stdlib/stdlib@0.0.84/dist/) which is comically large, and which will make bundling painfully slow. If you *have* to use this library (eek) then just include it as a `<script>` tag and access it as a global, rather than bundling it.

Comment: Many thanks for you help @RichHarris ! and BTW, great job with svelte! I could solve the problem with `import stdlib from './stdlib-flat.min.js'` in _App.svelte_. I will follow your advice and try to include it as a `<script>` (I am just learning so it might take me some time to figure out how). Unfortunately, this library is necessary for numerical and scientific applications.

Comment: I've come across the same issue, but it's not clear to me from the comments how to resolve it in the non-"bundled&slow" way - would really appreciate an explanation. Other than this, Svelte is so easy to get into!...

Comment: @jklizarraga You could try using the experimental ESM build, which can be found here: https://github.com/stdlib-js/esm. Otherwise, another option is to create a custom bundle of only the functionality you need and wrap accordingly.