# Import a working javascript file in Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm building an app in Svelte and I'm trying to add to it a previously written `.js` file. I tried to import it in the `main.js` file, but gives me an error:  `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetHeight')` This is the `.js` file:

```
[...]
function colorSubheadings() {
    // Replace subheading background colors
    var redStart = 255;
    var greenStart = 255;
    var blueStart = 255;
    var redEnd = 249;
    var greenEnd = 250;
    var blueEnd = 251;

    var redDiff = redEnd - redStart;
    var greenDiff = greenEnd - greenStart;
    var blueDiff = blueEnd - blueStart;

    var page = document.querySelector('.page');
    var pageHeight = page.offsetHeight;

    var subheadings = document.getElementsByClassName('.chapter');
    for (var i = 0; i < subheadings.length; i++) {
        // Get the position relative to .page
        var span = subheadings[i].querySelector('span');
        var factor = span.offsetTop / pageHeight;

        var r = Math.floor(redDiff * factor + redStart);
        var g = Math.floor(greenDiff * factor + greenStart);
        var b = Math.floor(blueDiff * factor + blueStart);
        var color = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';

        // Color background based on position
        span.style.backgroundColor = color;
        span.style.boxShadow = '11px 0 0 ' + color + ', -13px 0 0 ' + color;
    }
}
[...]
```

And this is the  `.svelte` file:

```
<script>
 //some functions
</script>
<div class="page">
[...]
<div class="chapter-sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar js-sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar__wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar__list">
            {#each files as { file } (file.name)}
                <li class="sidebar__list-item">
                    <a class="sidebar__link" href="#temp">{file.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')}</a>
                </li>
            {/each}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the `.svelte` file there is a lateral navbar, just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do4Sw.png). In vanilla html it works perfectly, but with svelte there are some bugs, like the navBar doesn't "stick" in a place: if I scroll down it remains at the top of the page, insted of remain in a particuar position of the screen, "following" the user's scroll. So, what can i do to use this `.js` file in my svelte project? I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839098/import-javascript-file-in-svelte) solution, but it didn't worked for me.
Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the `colorSubheadings()` function called?
(I see `var subheadings = document.getElementsByClassName('.chapter')` but no elements with class 'chapter' in the Svelte file)

I suggest you either try

1. importing the .js file in the `index.html` in `yourproject/puplic` folder **after** the `<script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>` (in case the function is called inside the same `.js` file)
2. run the function inside [onMount](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount) in the `.svelte` component (`.js` file inside `yourproject/src` folder with exported function `export colorSubheadings() {...}`)

```js
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    import {colorSubheadings} from './xy.js'
        
    onMount(()=> {
         colorSubheadings()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the function in your js file before you can import it in your .svelte file (or other JS file).

```js
export function colorSubheadings() {
...
}
```